# How to properly replace() on a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to use replace with a while loop. I want to replace the first letter in the string with an empty string if the letters is not a vowel. The regex I have used is working because the letters are added to the end of the string, just not sure what is happening with the replace function?

Here is my code:

```
vowel = new RegExp("[aeiou]");
word = "cherry";

var moved = '',
        i = 0;
    while (!vowel.test(word[i])) {
      moved += word[i];
      word.replace(word[i], '');
      i++;
    }

return word+moved;
```

For example, 'cherrych' will be returned rather than 'errych'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace` returns a modified *copy* of the string, and does not alter the string in place.

Every time you do `word.replace()`, you cause a new string to be returned but importantly *`word` is not altered at all*.

The right way to attack this is then to *assign* this new modified copy to the original by

```
word = word.replace(word[i],'');
```

Comment: `word = word.replace(word[i], '');`

Comment: @Liam Was in the process of including that in the answer when you commented :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop here, just use standard regex multiple selectors, e.g. see the following:

```
'cherrych'.replace(/^[^aeiou]*/, '')
```

Comment: This works but I want to limit the regex as much as possible, thanks

Comment: @pauld you use regex but want to limit it? What is then the point to use the regex at all? imo if you use something you should use it as good as possible, otherwise it is an overkill